# Angular: parse a URL into a route and params without following that URL?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Suppose I have an Angular app using a `$routeProvider` that I've initialized similarly to the following:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/foo/:var1', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/template-1.html',
    controller: 'SomeController'
  })
  .when('/bar/:var2a/:var2b', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/template-2.html',
    controller: 'SomeOtherController'
  })....
```

Now suppose I have a URL and I want to know information about the route it will map to (in particular, which route parameters it contains and what their values are) without actually following that route.  Does an angular service such as `$route`, `$routeParams`, or `$routeProvider` provide a function that will, given a URL, return that information to me?

As an example, if my site was hosted at `example.com` and I called such a function passing in the argument `'http://example.com#/bar/2/blue'`
I'd like it to return (something that contains) an object like

```
{ var2a: 2, var2b: 'blue' }
```

I thought since Angular's routing service clearly has the capability to map URLs from the browser's address bar to a route and list of params, there might be a way to harness this functionality for any URL in my application without actually navigating to that URL.  Is there?  If not, is there a third-party library/plugin that can integrate with Angular and do this?

(In case you're curious:  my reason for wanting this is so that if the user deletes an entity in my application, I can clear out any URLs in the application's "recently visited" shortcut list that reference that entity's ID so that the user doesn't try to navigate to an item that no longer exists.)

Thank you to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 0):

`$routeParams` is exactly what you're looking for. Your `SomeOtherController` would look like this:

```
.controller('SomeOtherController', function($routeParams) {
    var myParams = $routeParams; //{ var2a: 2, var2b: 'blue' }
});
```

*Edit:* After re-reading your post, I realize that you seem to want to do this outside of your controller, so `$routeParams` won't be the correct option for that scenario.

In that case, you can use `$location` to get the path and any associated queries, but you'll need to parse it and assign the object yourself as `$location` will be unaware of `:var2a` and `:var2b`. Angular doesn't provide a native function to parse URLs against your resource structure without actually routing to them, like with `$routeProvider`.

You should let the deletion controller handle the logic of removing associated content. Or at least kick off a task for something else to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more flexibility to find specific route elements and final component name within a complex URL structure, I find this method useful, fault tolerant and future proof.  Just change the `this.router.url` to the URL you want to evaluate.

```
import { PRIMARY_OUTLET, Router, UrlSegment, UrlSegmentGroup, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
```

```
    const routeTree: UrlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
    const routeSegmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup = routeTree.root.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET];
    let segmentList: UrlSegment[];
    let lastComponentName: string = "/";
    let firstRouteSegName: string = "";

    if (routeSegmentGroup != undefined) {
      segmentList = routeSegmentGroup.segments;
      firstRouteSegName = segmentList[0].path;
      lastComponentName = segmentList[segmentList.length-1].path;
    }

    console.log("first: " + firstRouteSegName);
    console.log("last: " + lastComponentName);
```